# Adding a stylesheet to WordPress Theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have the following code to where it's supposed to work.

```
function boom_theme_styles() {
    
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'boom_theme_styles' );
```

However, the style.css will not load. Looks like a basic webpage from the 1990s. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your function and the add_action call look OK. Are you certain that style_css is a unique name - i.e. no other style sheet could possibly be using it? Might be as well to have a more definitely unique name just in case. Are you certain that the style.css you want to enqueue at this point is in your theme's directory (not in a subdirectory like /css?).

Comment: @FlashThunder boom_theme-styles is not the name of a hook it is the name of their function and it looks OK because it looks as though it's likely to be unique.

Comment: Whatever I seem to do, it doesn't work. I've even tried, `wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . 'style.css' );`

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_enqueue_style('style_css', get_stylesheet_uri());
```

Comment: I think @RobbeeThomas is trying to set up the style sheet for their theme rather than find out what style sheet is already set up.